# Can't get Rewrite rule to keep original URL

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these Rewrites, but I would like to have the URL stay the same as what is typed originally, I thought removing the [R] flags would stop it but it hasn't

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplea\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://examplea.example.com:32400/web [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleb\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://exampleb.example.com:9091 [L]
```

Edit: would this work better?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hello.example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ welcome [L]
```

Comment: It will always trigger an external redirect if you specify a different port, regardless of whether you explicitly state it is a `R`edirect or not. However, you can get around this with mod_proxy. See this answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308088/apache-mod-rewrite-internally-to-different-port

Comment: I like using mod_proxy. Just use caution to secure your mod_proxy before enabling. Otherwise, it will not take long before the Chinese begin to send many 100K's requests per hour to your site.

Comment: ahh okay, how do you secure your mod proxy?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you would are trying to fetch data from a web service that is running on another port and display it using your main web server.

[mod_rewrite can be configured to do so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html).  You have to have mod_proxy enabled and use `[P]` with your rewrite rules.  Your directives might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplea\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://examplea.example.com:32400/web/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://examplea.example.com/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleb\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://exampleb.example.com:9091/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse / http://exampleb.example.com/
```